# Enabling two sided printing causes blank pages on the back of each page

Tags: printing, pdf, canon

My printer prints OK when two page printing is disabled. When I enable two sided printing, the printer prints on both pages (takes paper back in and prints on the back). However, all back pages are blank. All the pages are printed, no pages of the document are missing, but it is as if by enabling two side printing, the system starts to insert empty pages between the document pages. Any idea on how to resolve/debug this?

[image]

Comment: So when you enable double sided printing, you still get single sided out, but it works harder? I'm confused by your statement 'it prints on the back'.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use printing from another device to verify whether the problem is located to printer internal setting or it is Ubuntu print server issue. Easy way is to use your smartphone as a print source. See [Canon web manual](https://ij.manual.canon/ij/webmanual/Manual/All/TR7500%20series/EN/CNT/cnt_print05.html).
2. Maybe some internal setting in your printer has disabled two-sided printing. It is very hard to find and check all the parameters. Try to completely reset your Canon printer to default state. I successfully solved similar problem concerning my Canon printer.

## EDITED

(Addition after **ntg** response in comment below)

It looks that incorrect control commands are sent from PC to printer during print task. Did you install correct original Canon drivers? Please, what is exact type of you printer? Is it PIXMA TR7540, eventually TR7550? The Canon driver is the same for both. It is `.deb` package in the `cnijfilter2-5.50-1-deb.tar.gz` file which can be downloaded e.g. from the [Canon UK support page](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_tr_series/pixma-tr7540.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux%20(64-bit)). The driver should be installed by `install.sh` script available after the `tar.gz` archive is extracted.

Comment: (1) makes absolute sense. Should have mentioned, from my wife's windows laptop she can print two sided without a problem... :s

Comment: See my additional information in answer.